# Python SQLite3 Updating primary key when another entry is deleted

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Currently I am using a database for a student music lesson planner.

Whenever I delete a student from the database and then I add a new student why doesn't it add the new student with the ID of 1?

The code for adding data is as follows:

```
def add():
  add = 'y'
  while add == 'y':
    Name = input("Please enter the name of the student: ")
    Year =  int(input("Please enter the students year: "))
    Student = (Name,Year)       
    insert_data(Student)
    print("New data added")
    print()
    add = input("Do you wish to add another student? (y/n) ")
  display = menu.Menu.DisplayMenu("Student") #Adding student name to menu
  choice = GetMenuChoice() #Getting the user's menu choice
  ValidateMenuChoice(choice) #Validating that user choice
  main(choice) #Passing in choice into the main variable

def insert_data(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("records.db")as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "Insert into Student(Name,Year)values(?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()
```

and the database code is:

```
def create_student_table():  
    sql = """create table Student
            (StudentID integer,
             Name string,
             Year integer,
             primary key(StudentID))"""
    create_table(db_name,"Student",sql)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how most databases work; sequences only ever produce *new* values and not reuse old values.

This is both more efficient (not having to search for free ids) and a good idea. Imagine a system that integrates multiple parts, including your database. Then the User ID you just deleted could still be referenced in other systems as well. If your database would *reuse* the ID when creating a new user, suddenly those external systems are referring to a new user, leading to hard-to-untangle bugs.

If you *must* reuse numbers, then you'll have to specify an id to use explicitly instead of having the database pick one for you. You'll have to find your own 'missing' numbers in that case, which will be *difficult* if you are using the database from more than one thread or process.

Also see the [SQLite auto-incrementation documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for some more detail on how you can influence how new values are picked; you either get monotonically increasing numbers (which can produce gaps) or, if you add the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, a value to be guaranteed to be 'highest value ever used plus 1'.

Note that the default behaviour is to automatically generate a `ROWID` that is 1 higher than the values *currently* in use:

> If no `ROWID` is specified on the insert, or if the specified `ROWID` has a value of `NULL`, then an appropriate `ROWID` is created automatically. The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row **a `ROWID` that is one larger than the largest `ROWID` in the table** prior to the insert.
>
> The normal `ROWID` selection algorithm described above will generate monotonically increasing unique `ROWIDs` as long as you never use the maximum ROWID value **and you never delete the entry in the table with the largest `ROWID`**. If you ever delete rows or if you ever create a row with the maximum possible `ROWID`, then `ROWIDs` from previously deleted rows might be reused when creating new rows and newly created `ROWID`s might not be in strictly ascending order.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Oh okay then! I was just unsure on why it would do this! Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: did you try the insert statement directly in the database? i tested it in the database and it inserts as you want.

Comment: @Jaan: Now delete that row, and insert the same data again.

Comment: sqlite has a default rowid by itself, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I deleted the record, tried another insert and got a record with Id =1 again.

Comment: @Jaan: Yes, if you explicitly name the id. Not if you leave the id to increment. Which is what the OP is doing.

Comment: in his table definition he hasn't mentioned id as increment, but I tried  both Insert into Student(Name,Year)values('aa','aa') and Insert into Student(studendid,Name,Year)values(1,'aa','aa') after I deleted the record with studendid=1 but statement gave me record with studendid=1 again.

Comment: @Jaan: No, he mentions `studentid` as `integer` and `primary key`. See http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html, that makes that column an alias for `ROWID` and it'll autoincrement.

Comment: @Jaan: At question here is **why** sqlite will not reuse `1` after a deletion. You are inserting an **explicit** id=1 row. That is entirely different.

Comment: I copied and pasted his query for creating the table.

Comment: @Jaan: I know you did. I am talking about your `Student(studendid,Name,Year)values(1,'aa','aa')` insertion. **I never said you could not do that**. I am talking about leaving `studentid` `NULL` and having the database autoincrement.

Comment: I tried both Insert into Student(Name,Year)values('aa','aa') and Insert into Student(studendid,Name,Year)values(1,'aa','aa') same result.

Comment: I can attach some screenshots if you want.

Comment: if I change his creation  query to CREATE TABLE "Student" ("StudentID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "Name" STRING, "Year" INTEGER); then that is fine. but only Integer and Primary Key is not forcing. AUTOINCREMENT should be there in order to have the ID increasing.

Comment: @Jaan: No, not according to the documentation and my experiments just now. `studentid` **is** incrementing. The reuse of id=1 is surprising, and I suspect it has to do with the table being **empty**. Insert more than one row, delete some, then insert again, and the id does increment.

Comment: @Jaan: It appears that the way the OP specified the table, `AUTOINCREMENT` is implied.

Comment: right so far my table is empty and trying which works, I will have some records in there and try the same and will post you the result.

Comment: @Jaan: If you were to create the table with `StudentID int` then insertion of rows without `StudentID` does *not* auto-insert a value. That column then remains `None` and is not an alias for `rowid`.

Comment: @Jaan: Right, sussed it all out; I always forget that SQLite will re-use the highest ROWID if you deleted it; `DELETE FROM sometable WHERE rowid=MAX(rowid)` is not a good idea.